# Only root can log into the machine running xrdp

Tags: fedora, xrdp

Installed and configured `xrdp` and I am able to connect from a Windows `mstsc.exe` but only as `root`. I found this forum post dealing with the situation where the only user who can log into a machine running `xrdp` is `root`: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32062-Unable-to-login-using-xrdp-and-non-root-username

But

1. there is no `Xwrapper.config` in the specified directory on my machine. The commands `man Xwrapper.config` and `man XOrg.wrap` do not work.
2. and when I create this file as he specified and reboot, there is no
   change.

OS: Fedora 19 (it will NOT be upgraded for the purposes of this question)

How can I allow other users to log in via RDP and disallow remote `root` logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **sesman.ini** config file has entries for allowed users and groups.

look at `man sesman.ini` for the exact usage of theses keys.

- TerminalServerUsers
- TerminalServerAdmins
- AlwaysGroupCheck

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3:

```
sed -i 's/allowed_users=console/allowed_users=anybody/g' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

Answer (score 1):

via: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?325427-Xrdp-Only-logs-in-as-root

I used method in this post and it works!

```
echo "unset SESSION_MANAGER" > ~/.Xclients
echo "unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" >> ~/.Xclients
echo "exec gnome-session" >> ~/.Xclients
chmod 700 ~/.Xclients
```